# SQL Server, to normalize this much or not?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, normalization, database-normalization

I'm trying to decide if I should push a specific column to its own table or if I should use another method or constraint of some sort.

Lets say I have a table like:

```
tbl_Location

LocationID PK int
Address varchar(100)
City varchar(50)
State varchar(50)
```

Another another table like:

```
tbl_Store

StoreID PK int
StoreName varchar(50)
LocationID int FK
```

Question 1: So a store is required to have a single location, not more than one. Is it overkill to push these into another table, and create a constraint that disables the same storeID to be in more than one row, such as:

```
tbl_StoreLocation

StoreID int
LocationID int
```

Question 2: Is there a benefit to still using a PK identity/auto increment column if I were to put this in its own table?

In a rare event, a location might be removed from the tbl_Location table. If it is removed, in method one ( all in one table ) I'll have to set the LocationID to NULL. Method two, I'll have to use cascade.

To further complicate things, stores can have products, and that LocationID is simply their default location. When creating a product it defaults to their LocationID from the tbl_Store, or if I break it into another table, the tbl_StoreLocation table. So that pushes this further, such as:

```
tbl_Product

ProductID PK int
StoreID FK int
ProductName varchar(50)
LocationID fk int <-----
```

Or should I again have (And each product can only have a single location):

```
tbl_ProductLocation

ProductID int
LocationID int
```

I read about the deeper phases of normalization but what I need help understanding is the time/benefit/structure analysis for something this simple.

What do you think?

Comment: You would use a separate table ONLY if there were multiple locations.  No exceptions.

Comment: @Misunderstood Thank you. I've always done it exactly like that, but after reading a massive document on normalization it made a mess of my brain :)

Comment: Should state be a FK?  There are those that say it is not required for 3NF but I put list of valid values in a FK.

Comment: @Blam It should in a different type of application. I have a strange use case for it not being as such in this one. I should have clarified that.

Comment: Instead of "only if there were multiple locations," I would say, "always exactly one location and nothing else uses locations."  If you have multiple entities (not just `tbl_Stores`) that would want to use the same location, you may also want to have a `tbl_Location`.  Say if equipment is assigned to a location instead of a store or if you have warehouses that aren't stores and you want all locations in one spot.  In that case, you'd have to have multiple junction tables with your key constraints there. You might also argue that stores could have a null location, but that seems rare at best.

Comment: @BaconBits Yes there is a tbl_Location which has a PK for LocationID and the city and state. But Stores can only have a single location, and products can only have a single location. So a store has a single "default" location, but that store might create a product that has a different location other than their default, but still in all cases only a single location for any foreign key referenced tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Question 1:
If a store is required to have a single location, *not less than one and not more than one*, so it is overkill to push relation between store and location into another table. But if a store can have not any location, as its location might be removed, you should use `tbl_StoreLocation` table. In such case you should remove `LocationID` column from `tbl_Store` table.

For Question 2: Yes, there is a benefit to still using a PK identity/auto increment column if you were to put this in its own table. Why not? You still use it for relations.

A few words about products. You said - *'stores can have products'* - so product relate to store but to location, so product location is its store location. Only if you change this business rule you need to redesign your database in correspondence.

Comment: If a location is removed and that location ID exists in the Store table, isn't it okay just to set this in the store table to NULL? Nulls are allowed... instead of creating a separate table? In regards to product, when a store creates a product they can pick a location for that product, and the default location that is first selected is the store's location. They can select a different location though. It's a strange setup. I'm thinking a separate table is overkill for StoreLocation or ProductLocation as both can only have a single location.

Comment: As for me I don't use nullable columns in foreign keys. The reason is that in joins *The results do not make it easy to distinguish a NULL in the data from a NULL that represents a failure to join* as stated here - [Null Values and Joins](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190409(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Very interesting. In my particular case removing a location from the location table is the only thing that will cause the Store column for location to become null, but a location should really never be removed once in place. It would be an extremely rare occurrence, in which when the Store signs back in they'll have to set a new location, which by nature means they can't really be on the site any more.

Comment: So to clarify, it's more of a... what if by some small chance I'd have to eventually remove a location... very unlikely to happen.

Comment: If you need to remove a location you'll need to remove related records in `tbl_StoreLocation` and no any updates will be needed in `tbl_Store`. This is more consistent and reliable I think.

Comment: This is a great article that explains my exact scenario: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-set-null-and-set-default-with-foreign-key-constraints   I think your comments are valid... I'm just making sure I dont' have bad design if I go with what I have.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem like an overkill to have a separate table when a product and a store, both are going to have a single location. Seems to me, it won't be a bad idea to introduce a bit of `SCD` here. Why not add a `bit` column `IsEffective` OR have the `EffectiveTill` column which would have the timestamp corresponding to the date(default value `31-12-2999` and time till when the record in the tables `tbl_Location`, `tbl_Product` or `tbl_Store` is *effective*.

If a location is removed, just update the column `EffectiveTill` to `getdate()`
If the location of product needs to be suddenly changed, just update the `EffectiveTill` for that row to `getdate()` and insert a new row with the new `locationID`.

This process has two benefits. One. No nasty index rearrangements in future. Two. Book-keeping of historical data. You never know when you might need to get your hands on historical data.